# what is the difference between find_package and pkg_search_module

Tags: cmake

All I can say about those commands right now is pkg_search_module has some odd usage, where I have to write the dependency that I would like to have two times. instead of just once like in  find_package

```
pkg_search_module(ZLIB REQUIRED zlib)
#seriously two times zlib and once in only capital case‽
find_package(ZLIB)
#much cleaner but for some odd reason find_package does not work all the time
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[`pkg_search_module`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindPkgConfig.html) uses the [`pkg-config`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pkg-config) tool to determine the location of the requested library. This is mostly useful on systems where `pkg-config` is already in use, so you do not need to replicate all the information for CMake. Note that this approach has potential portability issues, since it requires `pkg-config` to be setup correctly on the build machine.

[`find_package`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_package.html) on the other hand is CMake's very own mechanism for solving the same problem. For this to work you either need a CMake find script for the requested library (CMake already ships with [a couple of those](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-modules.7.html), but you can easily write your own) or alternatively a [package config script](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-packages.7.html) provided by the requested library itself. In either case you might have to adjust your [`CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_MODULE_PATH.html#variable:CMAKE_MODULE_PATH) for CMake to be able to find the respective script.

The choice which one to use is quite simple:

- Always prefer package config scripts, if provided by the library.
- Use find scripts as a fallback for libraries that are not aware of CMake.
- Use `pkg_search_module` if you want to exploit synergies with `pkg-config`. In particular, note that it is possible to implement a find script using `pkg_search_module` as one method of obtaining the required information.

Comment: thank you very much. Can you also answer why pkg_search_module has a prefix argument instead of just using the library name?

Comment: @Arne Don't know the module too well, but afaik the prefix is only needed for the names of the output vars. So you can do `pkg_search_module(compress_lib REQUIRED zlib)` and then `if(compress_lib_FOUND) ...`. So the library name (the one after the `REQUIRED`) is determined by the lib, but you are free to chose whatever you want for the PREFIX.

Comment: I see that `pkg_search_module` finds `SDL2_image`, while `find_package` doesn't. Are there examples where `find_package` succeeds where `pkg_search_module` fails?

Comment: @user2023370 As the answer mentions, the two are completely independent, as such it is not unusual for one to fail even if the other succeeds. Consider adapting your find script in a way that it makes use of the information provided by `pkg-config`.