# Difference between FindOpenCV.cmake and OpenCVConfig.cmake

Tags: cmake

First there is

pkg_search_module() that looks for package config files ending with extension .pc

```
pkg_search_module(some_name REQURED package)
```

looks for package.pc in the PKG_CONFIG_PATH

Then there is find_package()

This has further three versions. One with

```
set(Package_DIR "/path/")
find_package(Package REQUIRED)
```

and other

```
find_package(Package HINTS "/path" REQUIRED)
```

and the third with

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/path/)
find_package(Package REQUIRED)
```

all look for PackageConfig.cmake or package-config.cmake

and then there is FindPackage.cmake.

All of them return the library, includes, found variables etc. ...

1. Which command in cmake looks for FindPackage.cmake?
2. Did I understand the concept correctly?
3. Why this complexity?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25959972/what-is-the-difference-between-find-package-and-pkg-search-module. Just note pkg-config is not as portable as either of the other two options, assuming they exist. And config mode of `find_package()` is the preferred option since it is for CMake-aware projects, not FindModule (aka module mode of `find_package()` which is for non-CMake projects) or pkg-config (which is not present on many platforms).

Comment: Its not a duplicate. My question is what is the signifigance of the file FindPackage.cmake. find_package looks for PackageConfig.cmake.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my question for linux users in the meanwhile. Maybe someone else can throw some more light later.

find_package has two ways to find the libraries and include directories. The default is Find< Package >.cmake. and if it is notfound, the search falls back to < Package >Config.cmake.

The default search locations are

```
 <prefix>/(lib/<arch>|lib|share)/cmake/<name>*\/          
 <prefix>/(lib/<arch>|lib|share)/<name>*\/                
 <prefix>/(lib/<arch>|lib|share)/<name>*\/(cmake|CMake)/
```

< prefix > is CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH - a path to be set in case the Package cmakes are not in the above mentioned default path. The default < prefix > path is CMAKE_SYSTEM_PREFIX_PATH

MODULE

Find< Package >.cmake.

```
set ( <Package>_ROOT /path/)
find_package(<Package> COMPONENTS lib1 lib2 REQUIRED)
find_package(<Package>)
```

CONFIG

< Package >Config.cmake

```
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH /path/)
find_package(<Package> CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(<Package> REQUIRED)
```

The correspeonding variables are stored in

```
<Package>_FOUND; <Package>_INCLUDE_DIRS; <Package>_LIBRARY_DIR, <Package>_LIBRARIES
```