# When would you use find_path?

Tags: c++, cmake

I am reverse engineering someone's code and I came across a line like so in the CMake file

```
FIND_PATH(OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR openssl/ssl.h
        /usr/local/opt/openssl/include
        /usr/opt/openssl/include
        /usr/local/include/openssl
        /usr/include/openssl
        /usr/local/include
        /usr/include
        )

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR})

FIND_LIBRARY(LIB_CRYPTO crypto PATHS
        /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
        /usr/opt/openssl/lib
        /usr/local/lib
        /usr/local/openssl/lib
        /usr/lib
        /usr/lib/openssl                                                                                                                                                     
        )
```

I come from a make background, so I would use something like `LDFLAGS=$(shell pkg-config --cflags --libs openssl` but I would never know what header file is being included.

It seems impractical/unfeasible to know every header file included in, for example, a large dlib project which links opencv and cuda libraries, so my question is this:

When/Why would you actually reference the header file by name?

Comment: The first example is searching for the include folder for the whole library by looking for a single header that is expected to exist. I have done the same in other libraries that I have created finders for.

Comment: @drescherjm this seems like a *poor man's* pkg-config. Does Cmake not have a better way to including of headers?

Comment: This is is about finding where the headers are. I have no experience with pkg-config so I can't compare the two on this aspect. Also this is for module writers. If you are not writing a module/finder you need not use this. Most users of CMake will never need to use find_path(). Instead they would use find_package() and the package / finder module would handle these lower level details.

Comment: I think the Cmake function `find_package(<pkg-name>)` is the equivalent to `pkg-config`

Comment: Indeed, cmake works best when someone took care of writing a "find*" module for you :-) They have quite a number of them installed with cmake: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/manual/cmake-modules.7.html Use `find_package(openssl)` (see the [doc](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/command/find_package.html)) to locate OpenSSL *and* the OpenSSL crypto libraries. This method is part of cmake and does not invoke third party tools, which is a cross-platform advantage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMake needs to support platforms where `pkg-config` is not available.

You are correct that the find mechanism is somewhat primitive. That is why CMake also offers [more sophisticated options like config-file packages or even `pkg-config` support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25959972/what-is-the-difference-between-find-package-and-pkg-search-module). The problem with all these approaches is that they require some king of external support. Package config scripts must be provided by the dependency you are trying to find and `pkg-config` must be available and configured properly on the platform you are trying to build on.

The various `find_*` commands have no such prerequisites. They simply try to find a file or directory the filesystem. That's what makes them the most powerful commands in a way, because you can always accept a hint provided by the user where to find the files (which the people in your example code did *not* do btw, so shame on them) and then the find can work its magic. But it's also the most inconvenient, as it's easy to mess up and tedious to use in practice.

So keep in mind that CMake's primary goal is to be portable. Don't shy away from whatever mechanisms your platform offers to make configuring the build more convenient, but also don't lock out people that are less fortunate and have to work on platforms where those mechanisms are not available.