# What features does Cmake have that make+pkg-config doesn't?

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, build, pkg-config

Lets me clarify the question in the title:

What features does Cmake have that make + pkg-config doesn't, **besides platform independency**.

Context:

- I code only for Linux systems, and use for my projects (gnu)make associated with pkg-config
- I **know** CMake is the de-facto standard today for large projects, and I have used it many times (as an "end-user").

Why am I asking this:
I have noticed that some (?) large projects dropped support for pkg-config to rely only on CMake.
[See Opencv here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/13154#issuecomment-438473073) for example, where it is said that "*Pkg-config has very limited functionality*".

Considering only Linux-based builds, what can I do with CMake that I cannot do with make+pkg-config, **besides** platform independency? Or is it only about that?

This is a real question, because I never encountered a situation where I felt I was missing some feature, but I feel like I **could** be missing something.

Please no opinion-based answers, **facts only**.

**Edit**: to clarify what I am asking for (I **know** CMake is a bit a "higher-level" tool than make): it seems that some think that
"*Pkg-config has very limited functionality*". My question can be reworded as "what functionalities lacks pkg-config?".

Comment: "Please no opinion-based answers, facts only." - What do you mean by "opinion-base answers" in your case? Do you accept "CMake is able to do XXX (which is applicable on Linux), but make/pkg-config cannot do that"? Or do you want exclusively "I developed the project YYY on Linux and find out that I need XXX feature, provided by CMake, but inaccessible with make/pkg-config"?

Comment: @Tsyvarev Not sure I get your point. To me, both are facts.

Comment: @kebs Something that comes to mind is the use of ninja build system with cmake, which is (usually) faster than simple make. While ninja is human readable, its files are supposed to be generated by a higher level build tool, like cmake.

Comment: You can make even what you want with Makefile... `pkg-config` just helps to fill flags (compiler's and linker's ones). CMake might also use `pkg-config` results to set flags, but generally provide/require other CMake scripts (FindXXX) to got those information. With Makefile, you have to write the rules yourself, CMake has higher level.

Comment: As stated by the previous commenter, CMake is just a higher level tool than Make. CMake could be comparable with Make in the same way as C language is comparable with assembler, or Java comparable with C, etc. You probably could rewrite a small C program on asm, but rewriting even a medium C program on asm will require much more efforts. The same is with CMake and Make: writing a small project is possible on Make too, but supporting even medium projects on Make will be very hard. Limiting with Linux only doesn't reduce CMake/Make differences to a small amount. Your question is **too broad**.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I see your point, but what if I say that differently: what benefit can I have from using Cmake? My view is that make is very powerful,(even for medium-size projects) and has I have a good knowledge of its usage, I am wondering is there **are** any benefits of CMake? The comparison with C vs ASM is a bit too much, AFAIK.

Comment: I did try to get into CMake, but as I couldn't see any advantages, I didn't carry on. Did I miss something?

Comment: @Tsyvarev Please see my edit, I don't think the question is too broad.

Comment: 'My question can be reworded as "what functionalities lacks pkg-config?"' - Well, you could ask about what advantages `find_package`, common way for search packages in CMake, has above `pkg-config` utility, common on Linux systems. I am not sure, but that modification of the question could be properly scoped for Stack Overflow rules. But I am really confident, that in the current form (comparing CMake with Make) your question is too broad.

Comment: Note, that CMake provides the utility functions which wrap functionality of `pkg-config` command line utility. That functions are provided in [FindPkgConfig](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.20/module/FindPkgConfig.html) CMake modules. So you could check some questions about this module and general `find_package`. E.g. look into that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25959972/what-is-the-difference-between-find-package-and-pkg-search-module.

Comment: Well, yes, that could be indeed part of an answer! From a quick view at https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html, seems indeed to have a lot of features

Comment: well you didn't say "features directly related to what pkg-config does", so I guess you could also count stuff like [`externalproject`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html) (being able to download/configure/compile dependencies from a network URL), compiler-independent feature flags like  set the c++ language version (i.e. 'std=c++0x' on older versions, 'std=c++11' on newer ones), manage compilation features like precompiled headers or unity-builds in a compiler independent way

Comment: @PeterT you seem to have some points, indeed. Wouldn't you write that out as an answer?

Comment: A big difference that springs to mind is automatic dependency management.  That is, changes in header files automatically trigger rebuilds of the C or C++ sources files that include them, all the way down the chain.  Doing this in Make is entirely by hand, difficult to get right, and incredibly damaging when you get it wrong.

Comment: @Peter That is indeed a very good point! I didn't even think about that myself, because I don't bother with that, I just add a general $(HEADERS) dependency to my targets, so that they get rebuild if _any_ header changed. But, yes, for large projects, that is a real issue! Consider add that as an answer?

Comment: `-MD`/`-MMD` gcc's flags allow to have dependencies, so can be done in pure Makefile too.